# how to use flock between C program and shell script

Tags: c, linux, shell, flock

I have a shell script and a c program

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for i in `seq 1 10000`
    do
    (flock -x 200                   // what is 200?
       ./taskA
    ) 200> lockfile
    done
```

in the C program, related code snippets are:

```
    int fd = open("lockfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT); // what permission should I put here?
    for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
      if(fd==-1)
            printf("open file fails\n");

      if(flock(fd, LOCK_EX)==0 ){      // lock the file
            taskB(); // here is what I want to do
            }

      if (flock(fd, LOCK_UN)==0)  // after finishing those tasks, unlock it
      {
            printf("C unlock\n");
      }
     }
```

I want to run the shell script and C program on the same host
and I hope they can run `taskA` and `taskB` at alternately, in different time
but I'm not familiar with flock, so there are some permission problems or open file failures

for example, if I run the C program and let it finish and then run it again, I get
"open file failure"
and the permission is

```
---xr-x--T 1 esolve 200036    0 May  6 02:18 lockfile
```

how to modify the scripts and code?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 200 in the shell script is a file descriptor — see the manual page for [`flock(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock).

Your problem with the file permissions is that `open(2)` takes 3 arguments when you include `O_CREAT`; the third argument should be the permissions on the file.  When you don't specify the third argument, you get some quasi-random value chosen for you.  It takes a lot of analysis to help you detect that problem because [`open(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) has the signature:

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
```

It is a variable-length argument list function, so using just two arguments is OK most of the time, except that when `O_CREAT` is specified it needs the third argument.

Comment: Add permissions to the `open()` call in the C code: `open("lockfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0600);` — but I'm puzzled that you can't deduce that from the main answer.  You can use whatever permissions you like; `0600` means you can access the file but no-one else can.  It is one of the times when it is really sensible to use an octal constant (using 0x180 is much harder to understand).